# How to get programming monitoring whatsapp text box to work?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, whatsapp

Good day everyone. I have this code to read a whatsapp group text box and monitor it for keywords in the messages written.

I am not getting any errors but the program does not pick up any messages that is written in the xpath area.

I do not know how to get my program to work. Any help will be much appreciated.

```
timport time
import random
import tkinter as tk
import winsound

from datetime import datetime
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service


edge_options = webdriver.EdgeOptions()
edge_options.use_chromium = True
edge_options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
edge_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
edge_options.add_argument("--headless")

# Replace with the path to your edgedriver executable
edgedriver_path = "C:/Windows/msedgedriver.exe"

# Replace with the path to your keywords.txt file
keywords_file_path = "C:/Users/evolz/OneDrive/Desktop/Coding/Whatsapp/keywords.txt"

# Replace with the path to your sound file
sound_file_path = "C:/Users/evolz/OneDrive/Desktop/Coding/Whatsapp/boing_x.wav"

service = Service(executable_path=edgedriver_path)
driver = webdriver.Edge(service=service, options=edge_options)
driver.get("https://web.whatsapp.com")

# Wait for user to scan QR code before proceeding
input("Press Enter once you have logged in and your chats have loaded.")

# Set up tkinter window for pop-up notifications
root = tk.Tk()
root.withdraw()

while True:
    try:
        # Get messages in chat
        messages = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value='/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[3]')
        print(messages)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        # If no messages found, sleep and try again
        time.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))
        continue

    for message in reversed(messages):
        # Check if message contains any of the keywords
        print(message)
        with open(keywords_file_path, "r") as keywords_file:
            for keyword in keywords_file:
                keyword = keyword.strip()
                if keyword.lower() in message.text.lower():
                    # Show pop-up notification with keyword and group
                    notification_text = f"Keyword '{keyword}' detected"
                    root.title(notification_text)
                    root.geometry("400x100")
                    tk.Label(root, text=notification_text, font=("Arial", 16)).pack()
                    root.after(5000, root.destroy)

                    # Play sound
                    winsound.PlaySound(sound_file_path, winsound.SND_FILENAME)

    # Sleep for a random amount of time between 1 and 5 seconds before checking again
    time.sleep(random.randint(1, 5))ype here
```

I have changed the xpath multiple times but no luck.

Comment: I'm puzzled since you're apparently running Edge in headless mode, but also the user is supposed to log in, press enter, and scan a QR code.